# Angular proxy config to change url

Tags: angular, proxy

The goal is, using proxy, to change URLs:

1. `/mock/service/getInfo` ----> `www.example.com/service/getInfo`
2. `/mock/service/submit`  ----> `www.example.com/service/submit-test`

So besides adding a target, in the first call we remove `mock` and in the second url we remove `mock` and add `-test` at the end.

I don't have problems with the first url, but don't understand how to write config for the second URL

Config:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [{
 context: [
    "/mock"
 ],
 target: "https://www.example.com",
 pathRewrite: {
    '^/mock' : '', 
    '^/submit' : '/submit-test'
 },
 secure: false,
 changeOrigin: true,
 logLevel: "debug"
}]
module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change proxy.config as follows. And create a .json file called 'proxy.config.json'

```
{
    "/mock/service/getInfo/": {
         target: "https://www.example.com",
         pathRewrite: {
            '/mock' : ''
         },
         secure: false,
         changeOrigin: true,
         logLevel: "debug"
    },
    "/mock/service/submit/": {
         target: "https://www.example.com",
         pathRewrite: {
            '/mock/service/submit' : '/service/submit-test'
         },
         secure: false,
         changeOrigin: true,
         logLevel: "debug"
    }
}
```

Then added a new parameter to package.json

```
{
  "name": "example-angular-app",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config=proxy.conf.json",
    "start-prod": "ng serve --proxy-config=proxy.conf.json --prod",
    "start-prod-sm": "ng serve --proxy-config=proxy.conf.json --prod --sourcemaps",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
        ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
        ...
  }
}
```

You can run Angular application using '**npm run start**' command.

Comment: Thanks, @Shehan! Do you know why post call stoped working when i added this proxy? I send the payload, but the server receives an empty one.